# Formulario no recupera Datos (Java - Spring)

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller

Muy buenas a todos! Tengo el problema de que al momento de recuperar información en un formulario, no me arroja ningún dato del objeto. Adjunto las partes del código y por favor, si pueden, diganme en donde tengo el error.

Este es el controlador de productos:

```
@Autowired
private ProductoService productoService;

@GetMapping("/productosInicio")
public String inicio(Model model){
    var productos = productoService.listarProductos();
    
    log.info("Ejecutando el controlador de Productos");
    model.addAttribute("productos", productos);
    model.addAttribute("totalProductos", productos.size());
    return "productosInicio";
}

@GetMapping("/agregarProducto")
public String agregar(Producto producto){
    return "modificarProducto";
}

@PostMapping("/guardarProducto")
public String guardar(@ModelAttribute Producto producto, Errors errores){
    if(errores.hasErrors()){
        return "modificarProducto";
    }
    productoService.guardar(producto);
    return "redirect:/productosInicio";
}

@GetMapping("/editarProducto/{idProducto}")
public String editar(Producto producto, Model model){
    productoService.encontrarProducto(producto);
    model.addAttribute("productoEditar", producto);
    return "modificarProducto";
}

@GetMapping("/eliminarProducto")
public String eliminar(Producto producto){
    productoService.eliminar(producto);
    return "redirect:/productosInicio";
}
```

Ahora el siguiente código es el formulario, que por ejemplo si relleno los campos con los datos que quiera y hago submit, los datos se guardan correctamente pero el problema es que no puedo visualizar los datos guardados para ver que cambios deseo hacer:

```
<section th:fragment="editarProducto">
        <form th:action="@{/guardarProducto}" th:object="${productoEditar}" method="POST" class="was-validated">
            <input type="hidden" name="idProducto" th:field="*{idProducto}"/>
            <section th:replace="producto/botonesEditarProductos :: botonesEditar"></section>
            <div id="details">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h4>[[#{accion.editar}]]</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="codigo">[[#{ti.codigo}]]</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="codigo" class="form-control" required="true" th:field="*{codigo}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="nombre">[[#{ti.nombre}]]</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" required="true" th:field="*{nombre}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="marca">[[#{ti.marca}]]</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="marca" class="form-control" required="true" th:field="*{marca}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="tipo">[[#{ti.tipo}]]</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="tipo" class="form-control" required="true" th:field="*{tipo}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="precio">[[#{ti.precio}]]</label>
                                        <input type="number" name="precio" class="form-control" required="true" th:field="*{precio}" step="any"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
```

Y la implementación del service:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Producto encontrarProducto(Producto producto) {
    return productoDao.findById(producto.getIdProducto()).orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: En el formulario que muestras la acción es `guardarProducto` y en el contralodor esta acción te redirige a `inicio`. En que parte le dices que quieres editar? La función `encontrarProducto` solo está en la acción `editar` pero no veo algún formulario con esta opción, salvo que en `guardarProducto` lo redirecciones a `editar` en lugar que a `inicio` .

Comment: Hola que tal?, mira te comento como lo comprendo yo (y te pido disculpas en mi ignorancia): la acción `guardarProducto` si encuentra un error me debería llevar a la página `modificarProducto` con los datos, pero sino guarda los cambios y me lleva a la pagina de `productosInicio` en donde se listan todos los productos, el cual debería observar ahí. Junto al producto tengo un botón llamado "EDITAR", y este utiliza la acción de `/editarProducto` de la siguiente manera (boton link) `th:href="@{/editarProducto/} + ${producto.idProducto}"` y al llevarme no recupera ningún dato del producto.

Comment: Entonces tú controlador de edición el parámetro debería ser   `PathVariable("idProducto") String idProducto` en lugar de `Producto producto` y tú método `encontrarProducto` debiera recibir el `idProducto`. Pon a este id el tipo correcto de dato

Comment: Disculpa, al ver lo que me pusiste revise nuevamente el controlador y el método de editar me estaba faltando declarar la variable "producto" (que recibe el producto encontrado) que es la declaro en el atributo que compartía. Muchas gracias, te agradezco!.
`producto = productoService.encontrarProducto(producto);`

Comment: Ojo que tú  estás pasando solo el `id` y no el objeto producto como tal.